# React-boilerplate injecting sagas to routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, redux-saga

I am using [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate) to develop self learning project.

However, i have a problem with injecting sagas to main `routes.js`

**routes.js**

```
{
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      getComponent(nextState, cb) {
        const importModules = Promise.all([
          import('containers/HomePage'),
          import('containers/NavigationContainer/reducer'),
          import('containers/NavigationContainer/sagas'),
        ]);

        const renderRoute = loadModule(cb);

        importModules.then(([component, reducer, sagas]) => {
          injectReducer('navigationContainer', reducer.default);
          injectSagas('navigationContainer', sagas.default);
          renderRoute(component);
        });

        importModules.catch(errorLoading);
      },
    }
```

I have a component named as `Navigation` and container as `NavigationContainer`.

**HomePage Container** which is the main container

```
import Navigation from '../../containers/NavigationContainer';

export default class HomePage extends React.PureComponent { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavigationContainer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And the error is like the following:

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: (app/utils...) injectAsyncSagas: Expected "sagas" to be an array of generator functions`

I have no clue what the problem is? Already search on github but found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the this practice solves my issue

https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/master/docs/js/redux-saga.md